# ANTLR4 mutual left recursion grammar

Tags: recursion, antlr, grammar, antlr4

I have read many questions here on StackOverflow about mutual left-recursion issues in LL(k) parsers. I found the general algorithm for removing left-recursion:

```
A : Aa | b ;
```

becomes

```
A : bR ;
R : (aA)? ;
```

However, I cannot figure out how to apply it to my situation. I have

```
left_exp: IDENT | exp DOT IDENT ;
exp     : handful
        | of
        | other rules
        | left_exp ;
```

The "handful of other rules" all contain regular recursion, such as `exp : exp PLUS exp`, etc. and have no issues. The issue is with `left_exp` and `exp` being mutually recursive.

I thought about just adding `IDENT` and `exp DOT IDENT` to the `exp` rules, but there are some situations where the other valid `exp` rules do not apply, where `left_exp` would be valid.

**EDIT**

I also have the following rule, which calls for a left expression followed by assignment.

```
assign_statement: left_exp ( COLON IDENT )? EQUAL exp SEMI ;
```

Since a regular expression is only a left expression if it is followed by DOT IDENT, it seems that I can't just add

```
| IDENT
| exp DOT IDENT
```

to my expression definition, because then assignment would accept any other valid expression on the left side, rather than only one of those two.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The approach I apply usually goes like this:

```
A: Aa | b;
```

becomes:

```
A: b (a)*;
```

Or in general: all alts without left recursion followed by all alts with a (removed) left recursion with unlimited occurences (expressed via the kleene operator). Example:

```
A: Aa | Ab | c | d | Ae;
```

becomes:

A: (c | d) (a | b | e)*;

You can check this easily by continuosly replacing A:

```
A: Aa | b;
A: (Aa | b)a | b;
A: Aaa | ba | b;
A: (Aa | b)aa | ba | b;
A: Aaaa | baa | ba | b;
```

etc.

In your example however you have an indirect left recursion (via 2 rules). This is not accepted by ANTLR. A solution is to move the alts from `left_exp` to the `exp` rule and then apply the algorithm I described above.

Comment: I had been thinking that I couldn't combine the two, because in the language definition there is an assignment statement that calls for a left expression, and an expression can only be a left expression if it is followed by DOT IDENT. I will update the question to include that information.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you are after, but keep in mind a parser is a syntax tool. It doesn't understand the semantics you are implying. You have to enforce them after parsing, if needed. From a parser standpoint it makes no difference if you isolate 2 alts in an own rule or not. However, ANTLR will not be able to parse mutually left recursive rules. Left recursion may only happen in a single rule.

Comment: Basically, an `l_exp` is what can be on the left-hand side of an assignment, either an identifier or dot identifier of an `exp`, while an `l_exp` is also a valid `exp` by itself. I was trying to avoid allowing something like `6 = 12` which is an integer literal on the left-hand side of an assignment. But it sounds like I may just have to allow that past the parser and handle it later.