# How to use antlr4 write a better parser that can distinguish attribute access expression, method invoke expression, array access expression?

Tags: antlr, antlr4

I want to write an expression engine use antlr4.

The following is the grammar.

```
expression
:   primary
|   expression '.' Identifier
|   expression '(' expressionList? ')'
|   expression '[' expression ']'
|   expression ('++' | '--')
|   ('+'|'-'|'++'|'--') expression
|   ('~'|'!') expression
|   expression ('*'|'/'|'%') expression
|   expression ('+'|'-') expression
|   expression ('<' '<' | '>' '>' '>' | '>' '>') expression
|   expression ('<=' | '>=' | '>' | '<') expression
|   expression ('==' | '!=') expression
|   expression '&' expression
|   expression '^' expression
|   expression '|' expression
|   expression '&&' expression
|   expression '||' expression
|   expression '?' expression ':' expression
|   <assoc=right> expression
    (   '='
    |   '+='
    |   '-='
    |   '*='
    |   '/='
    |   '&='
    |   '|='
    |   '^='
    |   '>>='
    |   '>>>='
    |   '<<='
    |   '%='
    )
    expression
;
```

This grammar is right but cannot distinguish between attribute access expressions, method invocation expressions, and array access expressions. So I changed the grammar to

```
   attributeAccessMethod:    
        expression '.' Identifier;

    expression
        :   primary
        |   attributeAccessMethod
        |   expression '(' expressionList? ')'
        |   expression '[' expression ']'
        |   expression ('++' | '--')
        |   ('+'|'-'|'++'|'--') expression
        |   ('~'|'!') expression
```

but this grammar is a **left-recursive [expression, attributeAccessMethod].** How can I write a better grammar - can I somehow remove the left-recursive property and distinguish these conditions?

Comment: I explained a rule to remove direct left recursion in this answer: [ANTLR4 mutual left recursion grammar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41788100/antlr4-mutual-left-recursion-grammar/41789097#41789097)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add tags to your different rule alternatives, for example:

```
expression
:   primary                                 # RulePrimary
|   expression '.' Identifier               # RuleAttribute
|   expression '(' expressionList? ')'      # RuleExpression
|   expression '[' expression ']'           # RuleArray
... etc.
```

When you do this for **all** your alternatives in this rule, your BaseVisitor or BaseListener will be generated with public overrides for these special cases, where you can treat each one as you see fit.

Answer (score 0):

I don't suggest you define your grammar this way. In addition to @JLH's answer, your grammar has a potential to mess up associativity of these expressions.

What I'm suggesting is you should "top-down" your grammar with associativity order.

For example, you can treat all literals, method invokes etc as atoms (because they will always start with a literal or an identifier) in your grammar, and you will associate these atoms with your associate operators.

Then you could write your grammar like:

```
expression: binary_expr;

// Binary_Expr

// Logic_Expr

// Add_expr

// Mult_expr

// Pow_expr

// Unary_expr

associate_expr
: index_expr                            # ToIndexExpr
| lhs=index_expr '.' rhs=associate_expr # AssociateExpr
;

index_expr
: index_expr '[' (expression (COMMA expression)*) ']' # IndexExpr
| atom #ToAtom
;

atom
: literals_1 #wwLiteral
| ...        #xxLiteral
| ...        #yyLiteral
| literals_n #zzLiteral
| function_call # FunctionCall
;


function_call
: ID '(' (expression (',' expression)*)? ')';

// Define Literals
// Literals Block
```

And part of your arithmetic expression could look like:

```
add_expr
: mul_expr                   # ToMulExpr
| lhs=add_expr PLUS rhs=mul_expr  #AddExpr
| lhs=add_expr MINUS rhs=mul_expr #SubtractExpr
;

mul_expr
: pow_expr                         # ToPowExpr
| lhs=mul_expr '+' rhs=pow_expr   # MultiplyExpr
| lhs=mul_expr '/' rhs=pow_expr # DivideExpr
| lhs=mul_expr '%' rhs=pow_expr    # ModExpr
;
```

You make your left hand side as current expr, and right hand side as your other level associated expr, so that you can maintain the order of associativity while having left recursion on them.