# Removing a left-recusion between 3 rules

Tags: parsing, grammar, antlr4

I'm trying to write a Lua parser with antlr4, but I'm struggling with theses 3 mutually left-recursive rules:

```
variable
  : NAME
  | prefixExpression '[' expression ']'
  | prefixExpression '.' NAME;

prefixExpression
  : variable
  | functionCall
  | '(' expression ')';

functionCall
  : prefixExpression arguments
  | prefixExpression ':' NAME arguments;
```

I have read the theory about left-recursion removal, but I just can't find a way to apply the theory to this practical case...

Thanks.

---

EDIT:

By using this refactoring rule:

```
A: Aa | Ab | c | d | Ae;  ->  A: (c | d) (a | b | e)*;
```

I achieved to remove mutually recursion:

```
// initial
// variable
//   : NAME
//   | ('(' expression ')' | variable | functionCall) '[' expression ']'
//   | ('(' expression ')' | variable | functionCall) '.' NAME;

// first iteration
// variable
//   : NAME
//   | ('(' expression ')' '[' expression ']')
//   | (variable '[' expression ']')
//   | (functionCall '[' expression ']')
//   | ('(' expression ')' '.' NAME)
//   | (variable '.' NAME)
//   | (functionCall '.' NAME);

// second iteration
variable
  : (NAME | ('(' expression ')' '[' expression ']')
  | (functionCall '[' expression ']')
  | ('(' expression ')' '.' NAME)
  | (functionCall '.' NAME))
    (('[' expression ']') | ('.' NAME))*;

prefixExpression
  : '(' expression ')' | variable | functionCall;

// initial
// functionCall
//   : (functionCall | variable | '(' expression ')') arguments
//   | (functionCall | variable | '(' expression ')') ':' NAME arguments;

// first iteration
// functionCall
//   : (functionCall arguments)
//   | (variable arguments)
//   | ('(' expression ')' arguments)
// 
//   | (functionCall ':' NAME arguments)
//   | (arguments ':' NAME arguments)
//   | ('(' expression ')' ':' NAME arguments)
//   ;

// second iteration
functionCall
  : ((arguments variable) | ('(' expression ')' arguments)
  | (arguments ':' NAME arguments) | ('(' expression ')' ':' NAME arguments))
    (arguments | (':' NAME arguments))*;
```

But I'm getting 'no viable alternative at input' :/

Comment: I've written such a grammar for ANTLRv3: https://github.com/bkiers/lua-parser/blob/master/src/main/antlr3/nl/bigo/luaparser/Lua52.g You could have a look at that.

Comment: The general approach is: combine all 3 rules into a single one with direct left recursion, resolve the left recursion and then refactor the resulting rule into subrules as you wish. Look at [this answer of me](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41788100/antlr4-mutual-left-recursion-grammar/41789097#41789097) to learn how to remove direct left recursion.