# Removal of indirect left recursion (I don't understand formal symbols)

Tags: antlr4, context-free-grammar, left-recursion

I've tried looking for answers to my solution but I can't seem to wrap my head around the generalized solutions. It doesn't help that I can't figure out which of my elements map to capital letters and which are supposed to be represented by small letters.

This is part of my grammar in Antlr:

```
expression
    : literal
    | unaryExpression
    | binaryExpression
    | priorityExpression
    | invocation
    ;

binaryExpression: expression binaryOperator expression;

binaryOperator
    : ADD
    | SUBTRACT
    | DIVIDE
    | CONCAT
    | EQUALS
    | NOT_EQUALS
    | LESS_THAN
    | GREATER_THAN
    | MULTIPLY
    ;
```

How would I go about removing the recursion in `binaryExpression`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By simply removing `binaryExpression` and using `expression binaryOperator expression` directly in `expression`:

```
expression
    : literal
    | unaryExpression
    | expression binaryOperator expression
    | priorityExpression
    | invocation
    ;

binaryOperator
    : ADD
    | SUBTRACT
    | DIVIDE
    | CONCAT
    | EQUALS
    | NOT_EQUALS
    | LESS_THAN
    | GREATER_THAN
    | MULTIPLY
    ;
```

### EDIT

> but now I lose the binary expression node in the AST and I have to detect it later in code

Then use [labels](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/master/doc/parser-rules.md#alternative-labels):

```
expression
    : literal                              #literalExpr
    | unaryExpression                      #unaryExpr
    | expression binaryOperator expression #binaryExpr
    | priorityExpression                   #priorityExpr
    | invocation                           #invocationExpr
    ;

binaryOperator
    : ADD
    | SUBTRACT
    | DIVIDE
    | CONCAT
    | EQUALS
    | NOT_EQUALS
    | LESS_THAN
    | GREATER_THAN
    | MULTIPLY
    ;
```

> Also, I'd like to gain a better understanding of how to remove this recursion instead of offloading it to Antlr

You can't. ANTLR simply doesn't allow such indirect left recursive rules. Only direct left recursion.

Comment: yes, but now I lose the binary expression node in the AST and I have to detect it later in code, effectively delaying that part of the parsing. Also, I'd like to gain a better understanding of how to remove this recursion instead of offloading it to Antlr

Comment: @MackThax check my **EDIT**

Comment: In addition to Bart's solution, here is an anwser from me where I describe an [algorithm to remove direct left recursion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41788100/antlr4-mutual-left-recursion-grammar/41789097#41789097).